# htacess config to serve static files and dynamic files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

the structure of my server is

**/build/** (a react application is deployed here) and **/api/** (a PHP application is deployed here)

I want to redirect traffic from [www.test.com/](http://www.test.com/)* to **/build**
and traffic from [www.test.com/api/](http://www.test.com/api/)* to **/api**

this is the current .htaccess I have

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+\.(js|css|svg|png))$ /build/$1 [L]

RewriteRule . /build/index.html [L]

# Rewrite the base route to /build/index.html
RewriteRule ^$ /build/index.html [L]
```

this rule works for fine for all test cases except the / (root) that one renders the root index file instead of the one under /build/index.html

Comment: yes I was writing to you.

Comment: @Developer I just updated my code the last part seems to be working fine but now everything is being routed to /build/index.html even /api/* are being sent to /build/index.html requests to /api/ should be intact

Comment: nope now it routes everything to build/index.html including the assets

Comment: the api now works but the react site doesnt work it throws 404. just to clarify the /build is where the react is deployed is not accesible by the public thatws why www.test.com/something should route to /build and the api is /api and that´s fine the way it is

Comment: that´s correct but when you hit refresh in the browser the route should still route to the react app otherwise you get a 404

Comment: I got it working! posted the anwser in case it helps. thank you for your help!

Comment: let´s see. thanks for your help Developer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255303/discussion-between-developer-and-handsome).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Rewrite requests to /api/ to the /api directory
RewriteRule ^api/ /api/$1 [L]

# Rewrite requests for static files to the /build directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^build/ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+\.(js|css|svg|png))$ /build/$1 [L]

# Rewrite everything else to /build/index.html
RewriteRule ^ /build/index.html [L]
```

This configuration will redirect requests to `/api/` to the `/api` directory, serve static files from the `/build` directory, and for all other requests, it will rewrite them to `/build/index.html.` The modification to the root `^` rule ensures that the root URL serves the correct `/build/index.html` file.

**edit:**

If you suspect the issue is related to the RewriteRule for the `/api/` requests, you can try the following modification to handle these requests:

```
RewriteRule ^api/ - [L]

# Serve PHP scripts under /api/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /api/$1 [L]
```

Comment: https://www.test.com/api/view.php?username=john is throwing the typical apache error "internal server error" all other rules are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(api)($|/) - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)\.js$ /build/$1.js [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.css$ /build/$1.css [L]

RewriteRule . /build/index.html [L]
```

this approach seems to be working

Comment: actually it doesnt work completely. requests to www.test.com are not being sent to /build dang htaccess is hard

Comment: you mean this [L] right? RewriteRule ^(api)($|/) - [L]

Comment: everything works except the homepage which is "/" I removed ($|/) but still not routing / to /build/index.html

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would write the htaccess from scratch to meet your requirements both in the written description as well as the code already provided:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ /api/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /build/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /build [L]
```

[Edit: fixed order -- gotta love copy/paste errors, my mistake!]

Comment: Lovely typo, thank you for pointing that out @EliezerBerlin